# How can I convert scss files for use as css

Tags: css, sass, converters

I inherited a website that uses scss files for styling specific pages.  I am not familiar with scss.
I just want to make a few changes.  How can I convert the scss files to css?

I tried a quick and dirty method of using the browser's inspector to copy the parsed css, but it seems to capture the pieces that make scss work. The online converters fail with undefined variable issues.  I am willing to do the homework, if you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a compiler for `Sass`, and for this you need: `NodeJS`, `npm` and install `Sass`.

[Install Sass](https://sass-lang.com/install)

So you need:

1. Install NodeJS;
2. Install npm;
3. Install Sass.

If you search the Internet you find enough content on the three and how to install in your environment (Windows, Linux or Mac).

Comment: Thank you.  In looking for this I ran across information that made me think sass is deprecated.  Am I wasting my time learning yet another way to do css?

Comment: As you said your project already uses `Sass`, so you are kind of "forced" to use it.
But it's not a waste of time to learn it, as it is widely used and I don't think it's obsolete.